# Easy way to convert ant lib jars to maven dependencies?

Tags: maven, ant, dependencies

Is there an easy way (some kind of script that I can download) that would ingest the contents of the `lib` directory where all the 3rd party dependencies are stored for an `ant` build into a list of dependencies I can put in my `pom.xml` for conversion to `maven`?

I have been using [this site](https://mvnrepository.com/) to find the `<dependency>` XML for each jar I have in the lib but I have a large number of jars and I am lazy.

Maybe a site where I can upload a dir listing from my lib and that would convert each entry to a maven dependency for the pom.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to start with the high-level artifacts and let Maven do its job?

Comment: I don't know which of my 148 jars are high level artifacts to start with

Comment: I bet you have some pretty good ideas. In any case, tool requests are OT for SO. That said, it'd be fairly easy to iterate over the lib dir, pull out version info of the jars that have it, and build up an explicit dependency list. Would I? No, I'd take the time to step back and figure out what the top-level dependencies actually are.

Comment: that would take more time than manually hitting the web page

Comment: Doubt it, but maybe you're faster than me at the web. The website doesn't tell you what version *you're* using.

Comment: `The website doesn't tell you what version you're using`: actually, it [does](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It tells you what versions are in Maven central.

Comment: my version is usually reflected in the name of the jar or i can go into the manifest to find out ...  most of the time

Comment: Right, and I'm saying it would take a few minutes to either grab it from the filename or from the manifest. I still wouldn't do this; I'd create a sane `pom.xml` and let Maven do its work.